# How to display the output of a webcam on a webpage?

Tags: webcam, html, livechat

I want to develop a live chat application. To this end I need both audio and video control on my website. Does anyone have any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use either Flash or Java... Google 'Flash webcam' or 'Java webcam'. eBuddy uses Flash.